# What is the difference between tasklet and workqueue

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, tasklet, workqueue

I am a Linux device driver newbie, and want to know the exact differences between `tasklet` and `workqueue`. I have the following doubts:

> 1. Which kernel stack do interrupts, tasklet and workqueue use when running in interrupt/process context?
> 2. At what priority would tasklet and workqueue run and can we modify it's priority?
> 3. If I implement my own work queue list, can I schedule/prioritize it independently?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Tasklets**:

- are old (around 2.3 I believe)
- have a straightforward, simple API
- are designed for low latency
- cannot sleep (run atomically in soft IRQ context and are guaranteed to never run on more than one CPU of a given processor, for a given tasklet)

**Work queues**:

- are more recent (introduced in 2.5)
- have a flexible API (more options/flags supported)
- are designed for higher latency
- can sleep

Bottom line is: use tasklets for high priority, low latency atomic tasks that must still execute outside the hard IRQ context.

You can control some level of priority with tasklets using `tasklet_hi_enable`/`tasklet_hi_schedule` (instead of their respective no-`_hi` versions). From [this IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-tasklets/):

> The normal-priority schedule is performed through the TASKLET_SOFTIRQ-level softirq, where high priority is through the HI_SOFTIRQ-level softirq.
>
> ...
>
> Tasklets from the high-priority vector are serviced first, followed by those on the normal vector. Note that each CPU maintains its own normal and high-priority softirq vectors.

With work queues, when creating one, you will use `alloc_workqueue` (`create_workqueue` is deprecated) and [can pass a flag](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/workqueue.txt) to ask for higher priority:

> WQ_HIGHPRI:
>
> Work items of a highpri wq are queued to the highpri  thread-pool of
>   the target gcwq.  Highpri thread-pools are    served by worker threads
>   with elevated nice level.
>
> Note that normal and highpri thread-pools don't interact with     each
>   other.  Each maintain its separate pool of workers and    implements
>   concurrency management among its workers.

I cannot answer all your questions, but I hope this helps anyway.